# PhoneGap app's XMLHttpRequest POST data lost

Tags: javascript, android, post, cordova

I'm porting an ajaxed, mobile-optimized website to PhoneGap, but have been unsuccessful in getting any POST to the server.  From what I've read, xhreq POSTS are supposed to be possible in PhoneGap.

The specifics:  I'm targeting the Android platform using the latest Cordova 3.3.1-0.1.2, the latest Android SDK, and a Galaxy S3 updated by Verizon to Android 4.3.  Connectivity is over wifi to my local server. In every attempt, the POST arrives at the server as a GET, with no post data (verified using tcpdump to inspect packets). The mobile-optimized web site works fine in the browser on the same phone, also over wifi.

I've isolated the fail case by creating a brand new Phonegap project, nothing more than:

```
$ cordova create Hello
$ cd Hello
$ cordova platform add android
```

Then in index.js, at the end of the onDeviceReady handler, adding a snippet I first tested in a simple browser page (domain substituted here):

```
// TEST POST CAPABILITY
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (req.readyState==4 && (req.status==200 || req.status==0)) {
    console.log("POST Response: " + req.responseText);
  }
};
var t = new Date().getTime();  // Just to foil any caching
req.open("POST", "http://mydomain.com/services/rpc?t=" + t, true);  // async
req.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/text; charset=utf-8');
var postContent = JSON.stringify({id:t, method:"misc.log", params:[{log:"POST Test"}]});
req.send(postContent);
```

And then run on the phone with:

```
$ cordova run android
```

It fails like the fuller app, arriving at the server as a GET with no post data.  I verified a couple of configuration item defaults to make sure they were as required:

In config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Any ideas as to what might be going wrong, or other things to look in to?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe that since the client and the server are not on the same domain you're having CORS issues.  It requires that you use jsonp, but jsonp will only allow GET requests.

Comment: The client in a phonegap app is actually the file system, so naturally the server domain will always be different - from what I can find in the PhoneGap docs & various posts, they handle this issue through the <access> config, defaulting to allow all domains (as above).  Just for kicks I tried (temporarily) changing the server side to allow anything as well by adding:        // Just testing, trying to get PhoneGap RPC's working...
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET POST");

Comment: I just noticed post #15260609, which is not PhoneGap-specific, but similar in the "POST turns into GET with dropped content" aspect - I tried the solution there (ending the URL with a slash), but it did not correct the issue.  Has me wondering if there might be some other cause for a similar "re-attempt with a GET", though.

Comment: On second thought. If your server is not local (per your post located remotely via internet), then testing the request with curl would help verify regardless (emulator or device). The idea is to test the request/response alone.

Comment: Nice, idea, checking it out with curl (didn't realize it could do posts, but there it is...) interestingly, that works, with or without the :8080 port designator - btw, I was not allowed to post a direct Answer, so I've added it to my original post - just realized that may not have been obvious...

Answer (score 0):

Your content type should be set to

`"application/json"`.

JSON.stringify() creates JSON content.

Next, can you tell us how your server process is determining the request type. Can you post the relevant code?

I would start by adjusting the content type value. See if that makes a difference.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's a tomcat servlet, with an HTTPServlet request, so request.getMethod() can be used to see if it's a GET or PUT - I also verified seeing the GET in tcpdump as well.   You're right that /json would be more accurate for this - I tried just that, as well as text/plain (after reading more info about CORS at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS, and trying to qualify as a "simple" request).. but that alone didn't do it.   I believe I've found the bogey though, I'll post as an answer here..

Comment: Thanx for the response. Are you running android on an emulator or a device? If it's an emulator, perhaps running the same request via curl might help you diagnose. You want to verify you aren't being redirected by the server (E.G. permission denied). I know not likely, I'm just using that as example. Verifying with curl should help.

Comment: I'm using an actual device, as I find they're a lot faster to work with than the emulators, and to be honest I doubted an emulator would be a good proxy for something happening at this low level on the phone.  But who knows, might have learned something there too.   I'm also curious about these add-ons that profess to allow you to use web Development Tools (ala Chrome) - but concerned that they too perhaps are designed for when you have things working at a higher level (i.e. basics coms sound)

Comment: Glad to have helped :) Please consider marking my answer as accepted, since the diagnostics I suggested appears to have answered the question. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an ip forwarding one, just not the one I'd originally suspected (forwarding to & from port 80 to my local server on port 8080, which I've used for years as a convenience to allow not having to add :8080 into the browser url all the time).

It was this:

In the MX records for "mydomain.com", I had www.mydomain.com pointing to my server's IP address, but the root mydomain.com (the host address I was using in the url to XMLHttpRequest), redirecting to www.mydomain.com.

This worked in a normal browser session, as if you type in mydomain.com, it just goes to www.mydomain.com, then runs from there - and it would use all relative paths in the xhreq's.

In PhoneGap, however, which requires the full path be specified, the POSTs were not making it through the redirect. It was also causing sluggish image loading behavior and some bizarre communication hangups after many loads - I just hadn't realized the problem had the same root cause (rather I was getting worried about WebView performance).

The great news is that POST is working fine now, and the WebView appears to be plenty speedy for my needs.

To summarize the solution: make sure that the subdomain (or lack thereof) in fully qualified urls passed to XMLHttpRequest (as required in PhoneGap) are mapped to an ip address (A record), and not redirected, in the MX records for your domain.